# Bad Message Return Path Warning - PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a simple contact form for a website, it says "Your mail has been sent." but gives and error at the same time, and e-mail does not come to my inbox.

Error is

> Warning: mail(): Bad Message Return Path in
>   D:\XXXAMP\htdocs\denemeson\index.php on line 38

I made the necessary arrangements about SMTP in php.ini and sendmail.ini.

```
    global $resultMessage;
    global $errorMessage;
    require("class.phpmailer.php");

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name= $_POST['name'];
        $email= $_POST['email'];
        $subject= $_POST['subject'];
        $message= $_POST['message'];
    if(!$name){
        $errorMessage="<br>Please enter your name..";
    }
    if(!$email){
        $errorMessage.="<br>Please enter your email address";
    }
    if(!$subject){
        $errorMessage.="<br>Subject..";
    }
    if(!$message){
        $errorMessage.="<br>Enter your message..";
    }
    if($errorMessage){
        $resultMessage="Please fill the required informations".$errorMessage;
    }   else{
        mail("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "Contact Form Message", 
            "Sender: ".$name.
            "Mail Address: ".$email.
            "Message: ".$message );
        $resultMessage="Your mail has been sent.";
    }
    }
```

Is there a way to get rid of this error and send the mail?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann: third parameter of `mail()` function is the message, OP can has many typo he want, won't affect the function

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = '';                 // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // Set the SMTP port
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '';                // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '';                  // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = "your name";
$mail->AddAddress($email, $name);  // Add a recipient 
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Make sure you fill the empty fields.